# Symfony2 JMS serializer force utf-8 output

Tags: symfony, encoding, utf-8, jmsserializerbundle

I am using FOSREST bundle along with jms serializer for my api application. I saved Bangali text in db and when returning the output i am getting

```
\u09e8\u09ea\u09ea\u09e7\u09e7\u09e9\u09ef
```

how can I force them to be converted to utf-8 when redering? even though I can get the real text in html if i set the utf-8 in HTML meta, i guess I'm suppose to have utf-8 response in my json.

next, when I am using

```
$language = $this->get('translator')->trans($entity->getContentLanguage());
```

to get a static text from yml translation file all I am getting

```
"?????",
```

i wrote that text in utf-8 format in yml file, also tried copying text from google translation, all im getting ???? what to do?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Ok I got it working for me with arabic. Basicallt when returning a response from the controller, I should set   $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); on the response object before returning it